# Regular Expression Matching if string is NOT surrounded by quotes

Tags: php, regex

The below function is part of a content modifier but has been modified and stripped for brevity.

What I'm trying to do is only change the matching numbers when they are NOT wrapped in quotes.

So assuming the string: **"1.222.333.4444" 1.333.444.5555**
the number ending with 5555 would be created as a link but the number ending with 4444 wouldn't be.

By not having the [^"], I can replace ALL of the numbers, so I know the middle part is working as I want it to.

```
function phone_link($str)
{
    $numlist = "1.222.333.4444|1.333.444.5555";
    $pattern = "/[^\"]($numlist)[^\"]/";
    $out = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($val){
        $number = $val[0];
        $short = preg_replace("/(?!\"*?>)[^\d](?!\"*?>)/","",$number);
        $short = ((substr($short,0,1) == "1") ? "+" : "+1") . $short;
        return "<a data-phone='$short' class='nounderline clicktocall' href='#'>$number</a>";
    },$str);

    return $out;
}

echo phone_link('"1.222.333.4444" 1.333.444.5555');
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The terminology you may want to search for is "*negative positive look ahead behind*", this may help you understanding how to look for things before and after your target pattern.

Comment: The other thing you can do is optionally include the quotes in their own capturing group, but just don't process them if you find quotes as part of your PHP function.

Comment: `(?<!")($numlist)(?!")` might enough